# Genesis - Didn’t God create Human with Wisdom?

Tags: genesis

Why was Eve not wise enough to say 'NO' during the Temptation by Serpent? "Their eyes will be opened after eating the forbidden Fruit and they will know good and bad". [3:6] ".......to make one wise"? Didn't God create Human with Wisdom?

Comment: It is said that wisdom comes from experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peace.

Yes, God has given mankind wisdom.

There are 2 kinds of wisdom:  the earthly wisdom where there is the living after the flesh ( behaving in envy, strife, seeking after one’s own vain glory….that is, wanting to be seen as “wise”…. etc ) and then there is the wisdom from above (the heavenly wisdom) of which one can live exclusively by  in this earth with the continuous sowing after the Spirit…..using the Spirit to put to death the deeds of the flesh.

The world is bogged down in the earthly wisdom (those who are after the flesh do mind the things of the flesh only) and is not focusing on those things above because much of the world does not have the Spirit of God within them to enable them to put to death the deeds of flesh and live after the Spirit only.

> *Romans 8:1-9 KJV (1)  T**here is therefore now no condemnation to them which are in Christ Jesus, who walk not after the flesh, but after the
>   Spirit.** (2)  For the law of the Spirit of life in Christ Jesus hath
>   made me free from the law of sin and death. (3)  For what the law
>   could not do, in that it was weak through the flesh, God sending his
>   own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh, and for sin, condemned sin in
>   the flesh: (4)  That the righteousness of the law might be fulfilled
>   in us, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit. (5)  **For
>   they that are after the flesh do mind the things of the flesh; but
>   they that are after the Spirit the things of the Spirit**. (6)  For to
>   be carnally minded is death; but to be spiritually minded is life and
>   peace. (7)  **Because the carnal mind is enmity against God: for it is
>   not subject to the law of God, neither indeed can be**.*

Those who are in the flesh (behaving in the worldly, earthly wisdom) cannot please God. To be carnally-minded is death.

> *(8)  **So then they that are in the flesh cannot please God.** (9)  But ye are not in the flesh, but in the Spirit, if so be that the Spirit
>   of God dwell in you. **Now if any man have not the Spirit of Christ, he
>   is none of his**.*

Yet Eve (who knew better) was deceived by the serpent to behave according to the earthly wisdom as she wanted to be seen as “wise”…..wise in her own eyes (being desirous of vain glory).

If one truly wants to be seen as “wise”:    Who is wise and intelligent among you? let him show out of the good behavior his works in meekness of wisdom.  (James 3:13)

> *James 3:13-18 KJV (13)  **Who is a wise man and endued with knowledge among you?** let him shew out of a good conversation his works with
>   meekness of wisdom.*

Envy and strife are of the earthly wisdom.  Where there is envying and strife, there is confusion and ever evil work.

> *(14)  But if ye have bitter envying and strife in your hearts, glory not, and lie not against the truth. (15)  This wisdom descendeth not
>   from above, but is earthly, sensual, devilish. (16)  For where envying
>   and strife is, there is confusion and every evil work.*

The heavenly wisdom (from above) is first pure, then peaceable, gentle, etc….of which Adam and Eve were to sow according to the Spirit within them in these things as God breathed the breath of life (the Spirit) into Adam.

> *(17)  **But the wisdom that is from above is first pure, then peaceable, gentle, and easy to be intreated, full of mercy and good
>   fruits, without partiality, and without hypocrisy.** (18)  And the fruit
>   of righteousness is sown in peace of them that make peace.*

We are free to eat from any tree in the garden…..the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, etc.  Against such there is no law.

> Galatians 5:22-26 KJV
>   *(22)  **But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, longsuffering, gentleness, goodness, faith, (23)  Meekness, temperance: against such
>   there is no law.** (24)  And they that are Christ's have crucified the
>   flesh with the affections and lusts. (25)  If we live in the Spirit,
>   let us also walk in the Spirit*.

But one is not to be desirous of vain glory ….that is, wanting to be seen as “wise”…and provoke one another in envy of another.

> *(26)  Let us not be desirous of vain glory, provoking one another, envying one another*.

Yet, the woman in the garden was persuaded by the serpent with the lie to speak evil of another as a judge supposedly for God.  Wanting to be seen as wise (desirous of vain glory), she put herself in the place of a judge (supposedly in His name or authority) to know what and who is good and evil.

> *Genesis 3:4-6 KJV (4)  And the serpent said unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die:*

The appeal:  “your eyes shall be opened”….that is, you shall be seen as “wise”.  Wanting to be seen as wise is being desirous of one’s own vain glory and is of the earthly, devilish wisdom.

The lie:   You shall be as “gods” ….Elohim (judges)…knowing good and evil.  She became judge, jury and executioner so to speak of another because she put herself in the position of judge knowing what and who was good and evil.

***(5)  For God doth know that in the day ye eat thereof, then your eyes shall be opened, and ye shall be as gods, knowing good and evil.***

She wanted to be seen as wise (being desirous of  earthly, vain glory) and did eat of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil.

> *(6)  And when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was pleasant to the eyes, **and a tree to be desired to make one
>   wise,** she took of the fruit thereof, and did eat, and gave also unto
>   her husband with her; and he did eat.*

As we know, death and life are in the power (hand) of the tongue.  We use our tongues to judge others…speaking evil of them.

> *Proverbs 18:20-21 KJV (20)  A **man's belly shall be satisfied with the fruit of his mouth; and with the increase of his lips shall he be
>   filled. (21)  Death and life are in the power of the tongue: and they
>   that love it shall eat the fruit thereof.***

Out of the same mouth proceeds blessing of God AND cursing of others who are made in the image of God.  As James says, this should not be so.

> *James 3:8-12 KJV (8)  But the tongue can no man tame; it is an unruly evil, full of deadly poison. (9)  Therewith bless we God, even the
>   Father; and therewith curse we men, which are made after the
>   similitude of God. (10)  **Out of the same mouth proceedeth blessing and
>   cursing. My brethren, these things ought not so to be**. (11)  Doth a
>   fountain send forth at the same place sweet water and bitter? (12) 
>   **Can the fig tree, my brethren, bear olive berries? either a vine,
>   figs? so can no fountain both yield salt water and fresh.***

Out of the same mouth proceeds blessing and cursing….but can a fig tree bear olive berries?   Either make the tree good and his fruit good or else make the tree corrupt and his fruit corrupt. It can't be both.

> *Matthew 12:33-37 KJV (33)  **Either make the tree good, and his fruit good; or else make the tree corrupt, and his fruit corrupt: for the
>   tree is known by his fruit.** (34)  O generation of vipers, how can ye,
>   being evil, speak good things? for out of the abundance of the heart
>   the mouth speaketh. (35)  **A good man out of the good treasure of the
>   heart bringeth forth good things: and an evil man out of the evil
>   treasure bringeth forth evil things.** (36)  But I say unto you, That
>   every idle word that men shall speak, they shall give account thereof
>   in the day of judgment. (37)  **For by thy words thou shalt be
>   justified, and by thy words thou shalt be condemned**.*

He that speaks evil  of his brother is being a judge and not a doer of the Law (to have love for one another).

> *James 4:10-12 KJV (10)  Humble yourselves in the sight of the Lord, and he shall lift you up. (11)  Speak not evil one of another,
>   brethren. **He that speaketh evil of his brother, and judgeth his
>   brother**, speaketh evil of the law, and judgeth the law: **but if thou
>   judge the law, thou art not a doer of the law, **but a judge**.***

There is only One Lawgiver who is able to save and to destroy.

> *(12)  There is one lawgiver, who is able to save and to destroy: who art thou that judgest another?*

But we see that the woman added her own carnal “law” (the added commandment of “neither shall you touch it”)  to God’s and presented it as though God had commanded it when He did not:

> *Genesis 3:2-3 KJV (2)  And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden: (3)  But of the fruit of
>   the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall
>   not eat of it, **neither shall ye touch it**, lest ye die.*

This (“touch not”) became a basis to judge another (speaking evil of them ….labeling them as “evil doers”) which is not doing the law to have love for another.

> *Colossians 2:20-23 KJV (20)  Wherefore if ye be dead with Christ from the rudiments of the world, why, as though living in the world, are ye
>   subject to ordinances, (21)  **(Touch not**; taste not; handle not; (22) 
>   Which all are to perish with the using;) after the commandments and
>   doctrines of men?*

The added commandments of men have a show of “wisdom” in will worship (as men think that they know for themselves what is good and evil by the keeping of man’s commandments and using those commandments to judge others with thereby provoking others).

> *(23)  **Which things have indeed a shew of wisdom in will worship,** and humility, and neglecting of the body; not in any honour to the
>   satisfying of the flesh*.

This nullifies the doing of the Word as men set aside the commandment of God (to have love for one another) in order to keep the teachings/commandments of men of which they use as a basis to speak evil of others judging those who do not keep them as "evildoers".  They become as judges supposedly for God.

> *Matthew 15:8-9 KJV (8)  This people draweth nigh unto me with their mouth, and honoureth me with their lips; but their heart is far from
>   me. (9)  **But in vain they do worship me, teaching for doctrines the
>   commandments of men.***

Answer (score 0):

What is wisdom?  See below:-

"wisdom  noun
the ability to use your knowledge and experience to make good decisions and judgments:"-https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wisdom

As wisdom is as in the above then no; as they would have to learn what "good decisions and judgment" from God but instead they took to deciding for themselves by taking the fruit of The Tree God told them not to touch, of the  knowledge of good and bad (which was in God's realm to decide for them), thus deciding for themselves what is to be "good and bad" showing a lack of wisdom.

Comment: "showing a lack of wisdom" does it mean God's Creation lacked Something (was incomplete)?

Comment: @Dee LeeThey were created with the capacity to be wise but it had to be learnt fist from God.  There were created with a blank page, so to speak, for a mind that was to be filled with infomation from God.